# Go bypass proxy

Tags: go, proxy

How can I bypass (ignore the proxy and use no) the proxy in Go?

Excatly I want to curl or http.Get to a website and check the response code.

I have this:

```
os.Setenv("HTTPS_PROXY", "")
os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY", "")

//Make Request and Check for Response

resp, err := http.Get("http://interneIP:80")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println("HTTP Response Code : " + strconv.Itoa(resp.StatusCode))

if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
    fmt.Println("Not OK")
} else {
    fmt.Println("HTTP OK")
}
```

But the Setenv cannot be parsed and with other methods I get the same error of cannot be parse to a url. So how can I ignore my proxy?

Comment: You should probably be using [os.Unsetenv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Unsetenv).

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own http roundtripper transport, you can see the roundtripper pulls in the proxy from env vars, you would have to set that to nil when you want to bypass:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper

Here is an example of a custom http client set up:
https://blog.abhi.host/blog/2016/02/27/golang-creating-https-connection-via/

Default transport docs also mentions you can use the NO_PROXY env var to exclude specific urls/domains from the default proxy, which may work for your use case e.g.

> NO_PROXY="*.aventail.com,home.com,.seanet.com"

I would guesss that in any case you would need to set env vars before creating your client so perhaps just make two clients using different env vars if you want to sometimes use the proxy and sometimes not.